# C++ - no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Object' to 'Object*'

Tags: c++, pointers

I am fairly new to C++ and I am having difficulties with pointers.  I have just created an object doing the following

```
  Object object("someText");
```

I then want to add it to a vector which I have a method for

```
 void ClassA:: addObj(Object* o){
     list.push_back(o);
 }
```

So when I call

```
 addObj(object);
```

I get the error:

> no known conversion for argument 1 from 'Object' to 'Object*'

How can I convert object to a pointer to pass it into `addObj()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

an `Object` and a pointer to an `Object` are two different things.  The compiler will not implicitly convert a type to its' pointer type. You have to do that yourself with the address of operator(`&`).

Change

```
addObj(object);
```

to

```
addObj(&object);
```

to pass a pointer to an `Object`.  That pointer will point to `object`.

I will point out that if `object` goes out of scope before the list you added the pointer to you will now have a dangling pointer and using it is undefined behavior.  You might want to look int a [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr) or [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) if you want to have ownership of the pointer

Answer (score 0):

See code below:

```
addObj(&object);
```

Answer (score 0):

`&` Allows you to get the address of an object. So `&object`, will give you the pointer to that object.

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to add a pointer to your object to your Vector, I assume, that an object allocated on the stack is not really what you are looking for. Better allocate it on the heap with `new`

```
Object* object = new Object("someText");
// ....
addObj(object);
```

Beginning with C++11 you can have a slightly more elegant syntax:

```
auto object = new Object{"someText"};
```

As NathanOliver already has pointed out, you should prefer to use `std::shared_ptr<>` or `std::unique_ptr<>`. Which one depends on who is responsible for freeing your object after it has been used.

If the vector class owns all the objects and they should be deleted as soon as the vector does not have it any more, then the vector should get`unique_ptr<>` and let users access raw pointers.

```
void ClassA::addObj(unique_ptr<Object>&& o) { // take a rvalue-reference here
    list.push_back(std::move(o)); // hand over ownership to the unique pointer in the list
}

Object* get(const size_t index) {
    // please add some sanity checks here
    return list.at(index).get(); // assuming, list actually ist a std::vector
}
```

If the User should be able to keep a pointer to the objects from the vector, that survives longer than the vector would keep it, use `std::shared_ptr<>` everywhere:

```
void ClassA::addObj(const shared_ptr<Object>& o) {        
    list.push_back(o);
}

shared_ptr<Object> get(const size_t index) {
    // please add some sanity checks here
    return list.at(index); // assuming, list actually ist a std::vector
}
```

Please also remember, that implementing your own vector/list/map, etc. is fine as an educational project. In production code, prefer to rely on the standard library. You most probably won't get it better.